# Wordpress files modified durning git clone (line endings, filemode or gitattributes did not help)

Tags: php, wordpress, git, lint

I'm aware certain changes may occur when cloning a repo from one OS to a different OS.  However, this is not just newlines added or space formatting (but that is also happening).  Chunks of code have been removed and modified completely.

I see newly added blocks, functions, .esc_attr and .esc_html tags.

I've played with .gitattributes files, set different core.autocrlf values and core.filemode values - nothing worked.

Also strange that only a subset of php files were modified.  All located under Ultimate_VC_Addons.

[git status image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJNdx.jpg)
[git diff image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEGwO.jpg)

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Most likely, that one plugin was updated independently of the git process.

Comment: I did think that but then shouldn't those changes be reflected on my web server and my local machine?  I don't have any auto-updates enabled in my production environment, I wouldn't think that would change on my local machine.

Comment: It's a *far* more likely explanation than that git decided to add some syntactically-valid changes into your site. :-)

Comment: True, I know it's not directly Git related, but it is a result of it.